# PHP session reset on every request

Tags: php, ajax, session, nginx

Its have been few days since I'm trying to get this work. I have problem with PHP sessions. Server is **nginx**. I have three sub-directories (sub-domains):

- **app.dev/**         (there is frontend, what client visit)
- **backend.app.dev/** (php page which proccessing AJAX requests, and communicates with API)
- **api.app.dev/**     (API)

In **app.dev/** there is `template/` folder which contains PHP files like forms, header, and parts of site which get populated by depending of session data. This is loaded into `index.html` page via `jQuery.load()` function.

On **backend.app.dev/** there is `page.php` file which process data, and send to API.

And then, when I send AJAX request on login action, and after I get token from API, I need to store it into session on `page.php`. At that request, it stores it successful, but, when I send second request, which check is there a token in session, it says that session is empty. I tried print whole `$_SESSION` variable, and it's empty. `$_COOKIE` also. So session get dropped after every request. I googled a lot. I tried many solutions ( I will post a log of solutions that I've tried.) And I found that there is files created after every request in `/var/lib/php/sessions`.

I tried to print session id on every request, and it's always different...

From log file, send the same request few times:

```
[28.Sep.2017 04:39:12]: session id: c0556q1s47kger3l53tgrdadhu

[28.Sep.2017 04:39:29]: session id: 83nmqq1l9d27v7jhh7748gq2ru

[28.Sep.2017 04:39:33]: session id: ece5as0eb0egoolun8u9s0duqi
```

There is a log what I've tried:

```
//session_name("backend");
//session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.dev');
//session_start();

//session_name('backend');
//ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'hr.dev');
//ini_set('session.save_path', '/var/lib/php/session');
//ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100));
//session_start();

//session_name("all");
//$sess_life_time = 21600; //in seconds
//$sess_path = "/";
//$sess_domain = ".dev";
//$sess_secure = true; // if you have secured session
//$sess_httponly = true; // httponly flag

//ini_set('suhosin.session.cryptdocroot', 'off');
//ini_set('suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot', 'off');

//session_set_cookie_params($sess_life_time, $sess_path, $sess_domain, $sess_secure, $sess_httponly);

//session_name("all");
//ini_set("session.cokie_domain",".dev");
//session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.dev');
//session_start();

//  session_name("mysession");
//  session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",".dev",FALSE,FALSE);
//  setcookie(session_name(), session_id(),0,"/",".dev");
//  session_start();
```

What could be the problem? Is something missing on the server conf?

I will be really, really thankful if we fix this as soon as possible.

**EDIT:**

I set session variables (start session) at the backend.app.dev/

**EDIT 2:**

There is `php.ini` info:

```
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 0 => 0
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => /var/lib/php/sessions => /var/lib/php/sessions
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.sid_length => 26 => 26
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_strict_mode => Off => Off
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0
```

Comment: Are you perchance calling `session_destroy()` on every request? Simple test: 
`print_r($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
print_r($_SESSION);
exit;`

Comment: Can you post some of your code?, so I can understand the cause of the issue better.

Comment: please paste your code **within the question itself**. There is no reason not to. External links can disappear, change or go stale. And why make people make more effort to read your question than they have to? Questions which need code and don't contain it can legitimately be closed as off-topic according to the site's rules.

Comment: @Scoots no, I'm calling it just when user logout. Everything is valid inside one request. When I var_dump session on another, it's empty. 


__BenyaminJeizan__ , Hey, I can, but just most important things, because it's commercial and I'm not owner, unfortunately.  Which part do you need?


__ADyson__ Well, I was afraid of it's robust. I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: If you set the session variable at `app.dev` then it won't be visible in `backend.app.dev` unless you set the [session cookie domain](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) for all subdomains to `app.dev` the code you shared tries to do this, but after the session has started (when it's too late)

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for opinion! I think I left it at the top of the page at first time, but at last I'd put it at the bottom. I will try again. And yes, I set session variables (start session) at the `backend.app.dev/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the issue, after so long... I kept the API on a separated domain, but installed front-end and back-end at the same domain, but in different sub-folders. So now I have:

- `api.app.dev`
- `app.dev` *(frontend)*
- `app.dev/backend`

And (native) sessions now working like charm. I also had troubles with serving these two sub-directories, so I opened a new thread. There's `nginx` settings I used:

[Serving multiple sites on the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642500/serving-multiple-sites-on-the-same-domain/46681315#46681315)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is setting up session for domain you are in (or subdomain).

You can set in php.ini

```
session.cookie_domain = "domain.com"
```

or

```
session.cookie_domain = ".domain.com"
```

Other option is to set cookie for whole domain eg. domain.com  with session token, and manage whole session form your script. Librarys that can be useful:

https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Session

https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Session

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I've already tried to set cookie domain to `.dev`, but that does not solve the problem. I will check these libraries. Thanks!

Comment: Nice libraries! I think this will solve my problem. What do you think, which one is better and more supported?