# Serving multiple sites on the same domain

Tags: php, nginx

I'm new at deploying, and basically this is the first time i get in touch with it. Short about application structure:

I have three parts:

- `api.app.dev/` - which is written in Lumen,
- `app.dev/backend/` - basic PHP middleware, used to keep API token and user data,
- `app.dev/` - which is front-end (JS).

I'm using `nginx`.
I spent so much time trying to set it up. The problem is that at `app.dev/` i have `/template` folder where PHP templates are stored.
At `app.dev/backend/` i have just one page which processing request
before it comes to API.  How configuration should looks like?

I successfully configured API. Front-end works for now, but i can't test it.

But can't get back-end part working. There is current configuration:

#### app.dev/backend

```
server {

    # Port that the web server will listen on.
    listen         80;

    # Host that will serve this project.
    server_name     hr.dev/backend;

    # Useful logs for debug.


    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access-hr-backend.log main;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error-hr-backend.log;
    rewrite_log     on;

    # The location of our projects public directory.
    root            /var/www/hr_app/git_repository/backend;

    index           page.php;


    location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://hr.dev";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;

        # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
        try_files  $uri/ /page.php?$query_string;

    }

    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # PHP FPM configuration.
    location ~* \.php$ {

            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://hr.dev";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index                   page.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    }

    location ~ \.js {
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    }


    # Set header expirations on per-project basis
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

            expires 365d;

    }



}
```

How do back-end part is accessed? 
- It's accessed via front-end. AJAX request is sent to URL below.
When i try to access: `app.dev/backend/?action=1123` i get `404 page not found`. 
On localhost everything works like charm. I develop with PHP internal server, and that was a BIG mistake!

Comment: "can't get back-end part working". What exactly isn't working? What goes wrong with it? You've given us no indication what the problem is.

Comment: @ADyson i'm sorry for information miss, but you just can write this, without giving negative vote...

Comment: Well firstly what makes you sure I downvoted? It could be anybody. As it happens, this time it was me, yes. I could just comment, but people respond more actively to downvotes...anyway I'll be happy to retract it once there's sufficient info. The downvote is for lack of clarity, which is a justifiable reason according to SO. Anyway...a 404 on one single URL isn't really sufficient evidence. Do all vists to app.dev/backend result in a 404? Or just that one? Have you checked that everything is deployed properly? Does your code work properly in another environment?

Comment: @ADyson :) i know, i know :)  But have in mind that permissions will also downgrade.

Info updated.

Comment: Your `server_name` directive is invalid - it seems to combine a domain name and a location. There can only be one `server` block for each domain name - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for the reply. But, i don't want multiple domains.

Comment: According to your question, you have two domains `api.app.dev` and `app.dev` - the latter domain supports both the `/` location and the `/backend` location. All configuration for the `/` and `/backend` locations should appear in the **same** `server` block, with a `server_name app.dev;` directive.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yeah, i get it. I've fixed it for the backend. But how to access `/frontend` directly if request is just `app.dev/`?

Comment: I think i get it. Just the moment.

Comment: Hmm. I tried to change at `app.dev/backend` `location /` to `location /backend ` but now failed to load front-end. At front- end i just have `location /`.

Comment: Ok, now i've succeed to get `app.dev/`, `app.dev/backend/` and `api.app.dev/` working. But, now i failed to render PHP templates from `/template` folder on front-end. How to redirect it to `fastcgi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i solved my problem by a lot of googling and trying. There are vhosts:

#### api.app.dev

```
server {

    # Port that the web server will listen on.
    listen          80;

    # Host that will serve this project.
    server_name     api.app.dev;

    # Useful logs for debug.
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access-hr-api.log main;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error-hr-api.log;
    rewrite_log     on;

    # The location of our projects public directory.
    root            /var/www/app/api/public;

    # Point index to the Laravel front controller.
    index           index.php;



    location / {

        # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # PHP FPM configuration.
    location ~* \.php$ {

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    # Set header expirations on per-project basis
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
            expires 365d;

    }

}
```

#### app.dev/ ( && app.dev/backend/)

```
server {

    # Port that the web server will listen on.
    listen         80;

    # Host that will serve this project.
    server_name     app.dev;

    # Useful logs for debug.

    root /var/www/app;
    index index.html page.php;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access-hr.log main;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error-hr.log;
    rewrite_log     on;


    location /backend {
          add_header Test "location /backend ";
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://hr.dev";
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
          alias /var/www/app/backend;

          # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
          try_files  $uri/ /page.php?$query_string;
    }


    location / {
         add_header Test "location / in frontent";
         add_header Test "location / in frontend vhost";
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "app.dev";
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
         root /var/www/app/frontend;
         index index.html;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         index index.html;

    }


    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }


     location  /frontend/template {
         alias /var/www/app/frontend;
     }

    # PHP FPM configuration.
    location ~* \.php$ {
          add_header Test "location php in backend ";
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://app.dev";
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
          fastcgi_pass                     unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index                   index.php;
          fastcgi_split_path_info    ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
          include                            /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param                  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        add_header Test "location ht in backend ";
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header Test "location css in hr.dev";
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        root /var/www/app/frontend;

    }

    location ~ securimage.js {
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        root /var/www/app;

    }
    location ~ \.js {
        add_header Test "location js in hr.dev";
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        root /var/www/app/frontend;

    }


    # Set header expirations on per-project basis
    location ~* \.(?:ico|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
            add_header Test "location ico,js,jpeg... in backend";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            expires 365d;

    }

}
```