# Ajax resets PHP session

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I know [this question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473875/php-session-reset-on-every-request?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) so I apologize ahead of time, but I have gone over his solution multiple times and it does not fix the session reset in my case.

I have a simple php page that outputs a session id for debugging. Like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

Then I have a simple HTML page with `jQuery` that performs an `ajax` request on that page and logs the output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $.post('http://localhost.api.mydomain/sid', {
        some: 'data'
      }, function(data,status) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Check your console.
  </body>
</html>
```

If I manually visit the url `http://localhost.api.mydomain/sid` the output never changes, the `session_id()` stays constant, as expected. However, if I refresh the ajax page, the outputted `session_id()` changes with every refresh.

I've tried setting `session.cookie_domain` in the `php.ini` file but to no avail. I apologize for this issue, but I simply cannot find a solution.

Comment: check your browser's debug tools on the "network" tab if the session cookies is provided with the HTTP POST request. If your request is cross domain, your browser security features may remove cookies.

Comment: Is there a way to program around this? It is for an API so expecting every user to change their browser settings isn't exactly ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `Access-Control` issue, not an `ajax` issue.

When you visit the url from your browser directly, you are requesting a (session) cookie from the domain you are visiting. When you are using `ajax`, in this case, you are requesting a cookie from a domain that is not the domain you are visiting.

On your php API file at `api.example.com`, try this.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Then on your `ajax` request file, use the `xhrFields` parameter like so.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.example.com',
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
```

Now as long as you are calling the request from the origin `example.com`, cookies will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the ajax request does not send the session id along with the request. That causes `session_start` to generate a new one.

Possible reason that could make the browser not send the session cookie during the ajax request is discrepancy in domain name.

instead of setting session.cookie_domain on the ini file, set it as follows at runtime

```
session_set_cookie_params(33600, '/', 'localhost.api.mydomain', FALSE, TRUE);
session_start();
```

To help you debug this, go to network tab on the developers tools in chrome. reload the page and check the request headers and response headers. check the host to which jquery sends the request. it may be sending the request to just localhost. and you may have configured your site to accept both localhost and localhost.api.mydomain.

to do more check, in your file, do something like

```
session_set_cookie_params(33600, '/', 'localhost.api.mydomain', FALSE, TRUE);
session_start();
die($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

this will let you compare the request url used by jquery during the ajax request.

Comment: I have tried putting `session_set_cookie_params()` in the manner you described, both above and below `session_start()`, but neither has fixed the session reset issue. Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: The requested host in the network console is `localhost.api.mydomain` and the output for `HTTP_HOST` in php is `localhost.api.mydomain`. Thank you for being so helpful, I really wish this solved the issue, but do you have any other debugging advice?

Comment: I would very much appreciate any debugging help. This is occurring on both a Windows 10 development machine and a Ubuntu 16.04 production machine.

Comment: ok, can we do this via chat? i would need to see the network section of the chrome dev tools

Comment: i will be glad to help as much as i can. i could replicate the issue as well as i am using the same ubuntu 16.04 too. and windows 8.1

Comment: this link is for stackoverflow chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ . if you are on watsapp, then, my number is +2348132083436