# session automatically reset after first treatment

Tags: php, ajax, session

Iam working on a multi step reservation form with PHP and AJAX
each Time i send the Ajax request to Store in the Session the **Session** automatically reset by it self i've tried to put the session_start()  in the header of the html index insted of the controller file any help please my code goes like

```
<?php
if (isset($_$_SESSION['data'] ) && !empty($_SESSION['data']) ) {
    array_push($_SESSION['data'],($_POST));
} else if (empty($_SESSION['data'])){
    $__SESSION['data']=$_POST);
}

var_dump($_SESSION['data']);
```

Comment: PS : By the way it Uses AJAX So there is no Page reload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax resets PHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514987/ajax-resets-php-session)

Comment: Please format your code in the future (I have done it for you now, just waiting on approval). If this is your actual code, try fixing your `$_SESSION` variables, at least 2 won't work if they are displayed as you added them to your question.

Comment: @TomUdding my code is format in my Editor but stackoverflow give's me a hard time when i try to copy and paste it so i have to re-write it && thank you dude

Comment: possibly the session is not started on ajax request only when html outputed. Another possible issue is that ajax uses different domain/cookie settings so session is resetted on ajax request

Comment: @NikosM. Any ideas how i can verify that !

Comment: Open your browser and see the cookies sent from ajax request, also make sure the server-side code that handles the ajax request indeed starts a session (not the code that outputs an html page but the code that handles the ajax request)

Comment: @NikosM.  i'am sure that the data has been stored in the session eachtime 
like when i submit my first form this is the response that i get when i var_dump the session 
array(1) { ["nom"]=>string(4) "mr-X"}

Comment: then possibly ajax request is using wrong domain for cookie settings